# nodejs koajs async await not getting value from db.collection.find

Tags: node.js, async-await, koa

```
    app.use(route.get('/allUsers',async(ctx)=> {
    var usersList = await db.users.find({});

    console.log("data",usersList);

    await ctx.render('BrowseAllUsers',{userlist:usersList});
}))
```

this is my code and i am getting [function] as output if i write console.log(userList) but if i write console.log("data",usersList); then i m getting

```
data function (fn){
  cb = fn;

  if (results && !called) {
    called = true;
    fn.apply(this, results);
  }
}
```

this output what is wrong

using

```
"dependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.13.2",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
"co": "^4.6.0",
"co-monk": "^1.0.0",
"koa": "^2.0.0-alpha.5",
"koa-bodyparser": "^3.2.0",
"koa-convert": "^1.2.0",
"koa-generic-session": "^1.11.3",
"koa-passport": "^2.2.2",
"koa-route": "^3.1.0",
"koa-static": "^3.0.0",
"koa-validate": "^1.0.6",
"koa-views": "^5.0.2",
"monk": "^3.1.1",
"passport-google-auth": "^1.0.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"swig": "^1.4.2"
```

}

AND node --version v4.5.0

how can i get list of users in userlist what is wrong with my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `db.users` is the result of `co-monk` wrapping a collection.

Since `co-monk` uses [`thunkify`](https://github.com/tj/node-thunkify), `db.users.find()` will return a [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk), which `async/await` cannot handle (I think by design).

Instead, you can use regular promises, which Monk supports out of the box:

```
// Assuming `db` is a Monk instance:
var usersList = await db.get('users').find({});
```

I found that you need to remove any calls to `co-monk`, otherwise its effects will "linger" and the above code will fail as well.

You can probably still store a reference to the collection in `db` if you like:

```
db.users = db.get('users');

// then, later:
let results = await db.users.find(...);
```

Comment: ok then it is not necessary to use co-monk in koa 2 or i have to

Comment: @PriyaPatil `co-monk` and Koa 2 will likely not work well together.

Comment: THANK. YOU! 
Spent 3 hours, at least on this.